# Fill a table with images without adding extra space

Tags: html, html-table

I need to build a 2x2 table where each cell contains only an image (20x20 size) without any additional space.

I tried to force the size of the image and the table cells, but the resulting table still has extra spaces. What am I missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/casaschi/M74nN/

HTML

```
<table id="myTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
       <td>
            <img src="http://pgn4web.casaschi.net/images/alpha/20/bp.png" />
       </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://pgn4web.casaschi.net/images/alpha/20/bp.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://pgn4web.casaschi.net/images/alpha/20/bp.png" />
        </td>
        <td>
           <img src="http://pgn4web.casaschi.net/images/alpha/20/bp.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="out"></div>
```

CSS

```
table {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
td, img {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myTable").offsetWidth + "x" + document.getElementById("myTable").offsetHeight;
```

Comment: In what way is this tabular data?

Comment: Use CSS and not a table! It will work better.

Comment: This is just an example to simplify an issue I encountered while working on a much more complex page. I know it could be done differently using CSS, it does not apply to my real life case. Just answer if you have a clue why the table does not follow the dimensions of the images. Just saying "don't use a table" is of no help to me.

Comment: @user1228226: Or maybe you don’t know how not to use a table in a convenient way! So if you could describe your real-life case, that would be good.

Comment: @minitech: never mind, a few people already provided useful answers below

Answer (score 10):

Applying `display: block` to your `<img>` tags solved the problem. Images are `inline-block` by default so I'm guessing that the extra whitespace around them caused the additional spacing.

Comment: Thanks: "display: block;" works perfectly (also "font-size: 0px;" works). Thanks to all that answered.

Comment: @pgn4web "font-size: 0px;" is exactly what I needed; because, I also needed to center ("text-align: center") the image inside the cell, which is not possible if the image is "display: block".

Answer (score 1):

Add `font-size:0` to `td`. The spacing is caused by the whitespace around the images having a default of 16px font size.

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Xgwka/

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to add `font-size:0` to your td rule:

```
td, img {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/M74nN/1/)**

You could also:

- Float the images left with `img {float:left;}`

Answer (score 0):

Use negative value of margin for td

```
td, img {
border: none;
margin: -5px;
padding: 0;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
```

}